# Modify nested parents procedure code to work with name instead of ID

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I found a great treasure that I looked for for months, an SQL procedure that lists all the parent categories to a child category, in order to generate breadcrumbs or provide category search suggestions. But it needs the category ID to find it's parents, I want to modify it to use the category name instead, as I am making a search box that provide search suggestions to show the category and all it's parents.

Code from [this link](https://devbank.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/get-all-nested-parents-of-a-category-mysql/).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getAllParentCategories`( IN idCat int, IN intMaxDepth int)
BEGIN
DECLARE chrProcessed TEXT;
DECLARE quit INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE Level INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE idFetchedCategory INT;
DECLARE chrSameLevelParents TEXT;
DECLARE chrFullReturn TEXT;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT parent_id FROM sb_categories WHERE website_id IN (@param);
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

SET chrFullReturn = '';
SET @param = idCat;
set chrProcessed = concat('|',idCat, '|');
myloop:LOOP
      IF quit = 1 THEN
        leave myloop;
      END IF;

      OPEN cur1;

      SET chrSameLevelParents = '';
      FETCH cur1 INTO idFetchedCategory;
      while(not done) do
          SET Level = Level + 1;
          IF idFetchedCategory > 0 THEN

                if NOT INSTR(chrProcessed,concat('|',idFetchedCategory, '|')) > 0 THEN
                      if CHAR_LENGTH(chrSameLevelParents) > 0 then
                        set chrSameLevelParents = concat( idFetchedCategory, ',', chrSameLevelParents );
                      else
                        set chrSameLevelParents = idFetchedCategory;
                      end if;

                      set chrProcessed = concat('|',idFetchedCategory, '|', chrProcessed );
                 end if;

           END IF;
           FETCH cur1 INTO idFetchedCategory;

      end while;
      CLOSE cur1;

      IF Level > intMaxDepth THEN SET done =1; SET quit = 1; END IF;

      if CHAR_LENGTH(chrSameLevelParents) > 0 THEN
        if CHAR_LENGTH(chrFullReturn) > 0 THEN
            set chrFullReturn = concat( chrFullReturn, ',', chrSameLevelParents );
        ELSE
            set chrFullReturn = chrSameLevelParents;
        END IF;

        SET @param = chrSameLevelParents;
        SET chrSameLevelParents = '';
        SET done = 0;

      ELSE
        SET quit = 1;
      END IF;
END LOOP;

SET @strQuery = concat('SELECT website_id, name FROM sb_categories WHERE website_id IN (',chrFullReturn,')'); PREPARE stmt1 FROM @strQuery;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END
```

My table structure is as simple as this:

```
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| website_id | name        | parent_id |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1          | Electronics |         0 |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2          | Computers   |         1 |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 3          | Asus        |         2 |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 4          | Food        |         0 |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 5          | Chicken     |         4 |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I am expecting when users search for "asus" that I get a table result showing "3-Asus, 2-Computers, 1-Electronics" in order to show in dropdown like "Electronics -> Computers -> Asus".

For now it works as expected if I use: `call getAllParentCategories(3, 10)` and I am hoping to get it to work like `call getAllParentCategories('asus', 10)`, but my SQL knowledge didn't help me.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the procedure so it accepts a category name instead of category id as first argument. The output of your procedure should remain unchanged.

One solution would be to add an extra step in the query that initializes the `idCat` variable from the `nameCat` argument :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getAllParentCategories`( IN nameCat VARCHAR(255), IN intMaxDepth int)
BEGIN
    ...
    SET chrFullReturn = '';
    SELECT @param := website_id FROM sb_categories WHERE name = nameCat;
    set chrProcessed = concat('|',@param, '|');
    ...
```

The rest of your code should remain unchanged.

Beware that this will work properly only as long as the category name is unique ... You would probably need to create a unique constraint on this column :

```
ALTER TABLE sb_categories ADD CONSTRAINT UC_name UNIQUE (name);
```

Comment: I appreciate your kind help. I just changed `( IN nameCat int` to `( IN nameCat VARCHAR(255)`.

Comment: @tinyCoder : welcome ! I fixed the datatype in my answer as well.

Comment: GMB, Hi again. Can you please provide a solution to avoid the unique name of the category? I have lots of similar names but under different parent categories, I need all of them to show up, is that possible?